# How can I define a setup and tear down for all tests inside a module

Tags: python, automated-tests, nose, nosetests

I'm using nosetest as my testing framework, and all of my tests are functions.
The test functions aren't inside a class.

I don't won't to decorate each function with with setup, instead I wish to define a setup & teardown function that will be written once and operate before and after **every test** in the module.

Does anyone knows of an elegant way to to this?

Comment: I was also looking into [setup_test](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/doc_tests/test_doctest_fixtures/doctest_fixtures.html).   
it has the needed functionality and I can't make it work

Comment: It's because that fixture is specific to `doctests`. You can find more documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/doctest.html) and how to integrate it into `nose` [here](http://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/plugins/doctests.html)

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior of `unittest`:

```
test.py:
import unittest

class TestFixture(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        print "setting up"

    def tearDown(self):
        print "tearing down"

    def test_sample1(self):
        print "test1"

    def test_sample2(self):
        print "test2"
```

Here is what is does:

```
    $ python -m unittest test
    setting up
    test1
    tearing down
    .setting up
    test2
    tearing down
    .
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    Ran 2 tests in 0.000s

    OK
```

Comment: I'm using nosetest and thinking of avoiding classes..in nosetest if you don't use classes you don't have these fixtures

Comment: There's no difference with `nosetests`. Why would you avoid classes ? It's contradictory since their purpose is to group testcases that share common setup and teardown functions.

Comment: I'd have to agree with @Grapsus here, you'd need a really good reason not to use `TestCase`, especially because it's so portable across all of the different testing frameworks.

Comment: I don't think the tests of one application don't fall under the pure definition of OOP,that is why I'm trying to avoid classes. Therefor I think the tests shouldn't be grouped into a class, since the only thing they have in common is the setup and teardown.

Comment: OOP and functional programming are two sides of a very very gray spectrum. The best advice anyone's ever given me was to use the best tool for the job, regardless of programming paradigm. In this particular case, this is about designing your tests, not your code. Using a class to consolidate setup and teardown is the standard design, and I would not let dogma prevent you from using it.

Comment: IMO it's not OOP here, since you will never instantiate the test case yourself. The class syntax is just used as a convenient way of grouping several functions. If you refuse to use it for some theoretical reasons, live with the ugly hack below.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be elegant but it will get the job done. First, in the package where your tests are defined, write to a `decorators.py` file:

```
def setup_func():
    "set up test fixtures"

def teardown_func():
    "tear down test fixtures"
```

Then, in a `tests.py` file, import the following:

```
from decorators import setup_func, teardown_func
from inspect import getmodule
from nose.tools import with_setup
from types import FunctionType
```

From here you can define all of your tests as usual. When you're done, at the very bottom of the file, write in:

```
for k, v in globals().items():
    if isinstance(v, FunctionType) and getmodule(v).__name__ == __name__:
        v = with_setup(setup_func, teardown_func)(v)
```

This will decorate every function defined in `tests.py` (and not the imported functions) with the setup and teardown procedures.

An important note though is that even functions that don't match `nose`'s criteria for a test will be decorated. So helper and utility functions will be decorated as well as the rest of your functions. In the vast majority of situations this will be a fairly safe operation. However, if you're concerned about it somehow mucking up your actual tests, you can define them in another module and import them in.

Edit: So this all works, and it fits the very narrow solution set you're looking for. No classes, per function decoration, no manual `@with_setup` decoration, etc. However, I highly suggest that you just move your test functions into a `TestCase`. It's painless, it's portable, and it's the standard way of grouping tests that have identical setups and teardowns.